# Nested loop leads to OutOfMemory Error: Java heap space

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to create an array list of string arrays containing all possible combinations of 0s and 1s, in four dimensions. That is, [0,0,0,0] is one combination and [0,0,0,1] is another. There are $2^4$ total combinations, so I'm using several nested loops to generate this array list. However, when I try to run the loop, I get an "out of memory" error. Take a look:

```
String[] t4 = new String[4]; 

ArrayList<String[]> list4 = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for(int i=0; i<= 1; i++)
{
String count = Integer.toString(i);    
t4[0]=count;
list4.add(t4); 
 for(int j=0; j<= 1; j++)
 {
 String count1 = Integer.toString(j);    
 t4[1]=count1;
 list4.add(t4);
  for(int k=0; k<= 1; k++)
  {
  String count2 = Integer.toString(k);    
  t4[2]=count2;
  list4.add(t4); 
   for(int m=0; m<= 1;)
   {
   String count3 = Integer.toString(m);    
   t4[3]=count3;
   list4.add(t4);
   t4 = new String[4];
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my loop? Or is there another way to generate the desired array list?

Comment: You forgot to increment `m` in your `m` `for` loop.  It's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have:

```
for(int m=0; m<= 1;)
```

You need:

```
for(int m=0; m<= 1; ++ m)
```

Otherwise it's an infinite loop that ultimately ends up filling up `list4` with `String[4]`'s until you run out of memory.

By not incrementing `m`, `m` stays at 0 and the loop condition is always true.

Comment: Good catch, and quick as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't modify `m`

Change this

```
for(int m=0; m<= 1;)
```

to

```
for(int m=0; m<= 1;m++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your inner 'FOR' loop, you forgot to increment variable 'm' and hence it is going into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with absence of an m++. Also, the loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<= 1; i++)
{
String count = Integer.toString(i);    
 for(int j=0; j<= 1; j++)
 {
 String count1 = Integer.toString(j);    
  for(int k=0; k<= 1; k++)
  {  
  String count2 = Integer.toString(k);    
   for(int m=0; m<= 1;m++)
   {
   String count3 = Integer.toString(m);    
   t4[0]=count;   
   t4[1]=count1;
   t4[2]=count2;    
   t4[3]=count3;
   list4.add(t4);
   t4 = new String[4];
   }
  }
 }
}
```